# Recovery in vim fails

Tags: vim, recovery

I have some problem recovering a crashed file in vim. I have an .test.py.swp file which contains also some readable lines, among others also the string `choice`. When I try to open the corresponding test.py file with vim either using the `-r` option or opening and pressing `R` or `E` the string is not there. It gives me the message:

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".analyze_minima_results.py.swp"
          owned by: sringe   dated: Sun Oct 15 14:37:00 2017
         file name: /scratch/users/sringe/MinimaHopping/analyze_minima_results.py
          modified: YES
         user name: sringe   host name: sherlock-ln01.stanford.edu
        process ID: 22589
While opening file "analyze_minima_results.py"
             dated: Sun Oct 15 12:32:49 2017

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r analyze_minima_results.py"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file ".analyze_minima_results.py.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file ".analyze_minima_results.py.swp" already exists!
"analyze_minima_results.py" 382L, 11693C
Using swap file ".analyze_minima_results.py.swp"
Original file "/scratch/users/sringe/MinimaHopping/analyze_minima_results.py"
E308: Warning: Original file may have been changed
Recovery completed. You should check if everything is OK.
(You might want to write out this file under another name
and run diff with the original file to check for changes)
You may want to delete the .swp file now.
```

It seems like something went wrong, because the recovered file does not contain the string `choice`. Is there any other option of recovering the `.swp` file fully? I really need the code in the file...

I could actually fine a way to recover the file from an `.nfsxxxxxxx` backup file in the directory. Would be nice anyways how to deal with such an issue

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the `.py.swp` file did not fit together with the still existing `.py` file that is why vim always reopened the `.py` file. Removing the `.py` file and opening the `.py.swp` via `vim -r` solved the issue.